# Java Map, filter with values properties

Tags: java, dictionary, filter

I have a

```
TreeMap resMap new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

I would like to filter and keep only entries that values contains a known pair, let's say ('mike' => 'jordan'), and avoid a loop like below

Is there in my included libraries apache.commons and google.common a filter method (that probably would do a loop too, but at least it's less verbose

```
for (Entry<String, TreeMap<String, String>> el : resMap.entrySet()){
    if (el.getValue().get("mike").equals("jordan")){
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some sort of DotNet's LINQ equivalent in Java...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? Anything you use is like to use a loop for you.

Comment: Minor comment: switch the order in the equals, since get("mike") could return null.  i.e.  `if ("jordan".equals(el.getValue().get("mike"))`

Comment: @PeterLawrey, "Anything you use is like to use a loop for you." That's a pointless argument. This analogy might help see why is that: "I want to avoid goto instructions. Does $lang support proper loops?" "Why do you want loops? They're anyway likely to use goto internally." Like that, you can go all the way down upto raw bits.

Comment: @missingfaktor There are plenty of reasons to avoid `goto`, but avoiding them because you don't like them isn't one of them.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, who is talking about "liking" here? There are plenty reasons to avoid loops. Loops lead to: 1. a lot of code duplication. 2. special case handling. 3. More cyclomatic complexity. 3. More chances of error, as a result of first three bullets. 4. Hard to follow code. (These bullets [may seem strange](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html) if you do not that ther exist alternatives for loops. [This link](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/fp.html) might help.)

Comment: @missingfaktor I am more than happy to work with functional languages which handle mapping and transformation cleanly. Java is not a functional language and while it may be verbose for procedural code, it is often even more verbose and unnatural for functional code. Functional programming in Java leads to more errors because it not the natural structure. As most Java developers are not familiar with it, it leads to greater opportunities to get it wrong. (I developed and supported a functional library for a bank for 2.5 years)

Comment: I use functionaljava extensively, and I strongly disagree with you that in Java it would lead to greater opportunities to get things wrong. The added verbosity is structural, not logical. After a while your eyes get trained to ignore the cruft impertinent to the logic of the program. Secondly, some IDEs have [some cool features](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/closure-folding-in-intellij-idea-9-maia/) that make coping with anonymous classes easier.

Comment: @missingfaktor I agree with what you say and I believe Java 8 will make a big difference to the cruft and you will see more functinal style programming. BTW: I am using a library which I wrote which uses predicates, so I am not against them. But in most simple examples they are overkill and not the best choice IMHO. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @missingfaktor Imagine you are hiring a Java developer to support your code because you want to move on to something else. How easy is it to find some one who is happy to use functional java in Java and will be more productive because of it?

Comment: You have got a valid point there. The probability of finding one comfortable using functionaljava is very low, but I'd at least expect him to be familiar and comfortable with some functional patterns, such as the ones popularized by Guava.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use filters from Guava and the `Predicate` interface.

```
Predicate<T> yourFilter = new Predicate<T>() {
    public boolean apply(T o) {
        // your filter
    }
};
```

So, simple example would be:

```
Predicate<Integer> evenFilter = new Predicate<Integer>() {
    public boolean apply(Integer i) {
        return (i % 2 == 0);
    }
};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

Map<Integer, Integer> evenMap = Maps.filterValues(map, evenFilter);
```

Comment: I think, though guava filter takes same amount of time whether larger or smaller map, but using iteration for small sized maps would give better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than force your client code to use a filter/loop, build what you need into the API of your class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private TreeMap resMap new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    public void filter(String key, String value) {
        // Some impl here. Either your loop or the guava approach
    }
}
```

BTW, if you use your loop, consider changing to this:

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<String, String>>> i = resMap.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<String, String>> entry = i.next();
    if (value.equals(entry.getValue().get(key))) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

The changes to the loop are:

- Changed order of equals to avoid NPE
- Using `iterator` to allow removal of entries directly

---

Even if you don't have a class, you could easily wrap it up in a static method on a utility class, where it could also easily be parameterized to work with any nested map:

```
public static <K1, K2, V> void filter(Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> map, K2 key, V value) {
    // Some impl here
}
```

Here's a non-guava impl for the static method:

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<K1, Map<K2, V>>> i = map.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<K1, Map<K2, V>> entry = i.next();
    if (value.equals(entry.getValue().get(key))) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov Fine, but that's an implementation choice. The main thrust of this answer is to provide an API so the client code doesn't need to know about guava/loops etc. I've edited the answer to say this.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov Rather than re-inventing the loop, just use a loop which is a language construct. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey do you realize that your comment can be replaced by a loop?

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov do you mean my statement is self referential?

Answer (score 1):

[From @Ferrybig answer in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863686/3107798)

You can use the Java 8 method [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) for this purpose:

```
map.values().removeIf(Object o -> o.get("mike").equals("jordan"));
```

This removed all values that match the predicate.

<kbd>[Online demo](https://ideone.com/KoYZby)</kbd>

This works by the fact that calling `.values()` for a HashMap returns a collection that delegated modifications back to the HashMap itself, meaning that our call for `removeIf()` actually changes the HashMap (this doesn't work on all java Map's)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Predicates](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Predicates) and [Functions](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Functions).

Comment: Naturally! They also remove duplication of such loops from the user's code.

Comment: And replace them with predicates which can be longer than the loops they replace. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey But who cares if performance is OK. It makes your base smaller and is semantically easier to understand. It may also let you deal abstractly with the data, leaving the implementation to decide how/what to filter. Just to be clear, I too think the OP is asking the wrong question and that this isn't the way to go, but nevertheless it's not without merit

Comment: Well, to be fair, these mostly return _views_.

Comment: @Bohemian what is always baffled me is the need to replace a loop with something more complicated. Often the loop is the shortest and cleanest way to do this. It can be slightly faster, but as you say that doesn't matter most of the time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Good point, if you need a *view* then using a predicate makes sense i.e. it will make other code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples. The both print the key based on match in the value's properties.

```
private static void printMatchingEntriesUsingALoop(Map<String, Map<String, String>> resMap, String key, String value) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : resMap.entrySet())
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue().get(key)))
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}

private static void printMatchingEntriesUsingGuava(Map<String, Map<String, String>> resMap, final String key, final String value) {
    Predicate<Map<String, String>> keyValueMatch = 
    new Predicate<Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable Map<String, String> stringStringMap) {
            return value.equals(stringStringMap.get(key));
        }
    };

    Maps.EntryTransformer<String, Map<String, String>, Void> printKeys = 
    new Maps.EntryTransformer<String, Map<String, String>, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void transformEntry(@Nullable String s, 
                 @Nullable Map<String, String> stringStringMap) {
            System.out.println(s);
            return null;
        }
    };

    Maps.transformEntries(Maps.filterValues(resMap, keyValueMatch), printKeys);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> resMap = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    printMatchingEntriesUsingALoop(resMap, "first", "mike");
    printMatchingEntriesUsingGuava(resMap, "first", "mike");
}
```

One uses a loop and one use Guava.

While the first one performs better, you should really decide which will be the easiest to understand and maintain.

Some suggestions from @missingfaktor. You have to use your own judgement, but he highlighted some of the issues well.

1. a lot of code duplication.
2. special case handling.
3. More cyclomatic complexity.
4. More chances of error, as a result of first three bullets.
5. Hard to follow code.

Imagine you are a new developer who has to support this software. Which would you rather be facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the map using java 8 and streams. The first step in this process is converting to a stream using `entrySet().stream()`. This gives you a `Stream<Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<String, String>>`. You can then use `filter(...)` to filter the list. When you filter, you should return true when the incoming value should be included in the filter result. After you filtered the results, you can use foreach to loop over the final result.

The final result will look like the following:

```
resMap.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(e -> el.getValue().get("mike").equals("jordan"))
      .foreach(e -> {
        // Do something with your entry here
      });
```